# Come support the new Hebrew.SE proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A bunch of MY users had supported the [original Hebrew.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language). That was eventually closed for inactivity.

There's now a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language) for it. Anyone interested can come follow it!

Comment: Can we just reask proposed questions from the original proposal?

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1398/759

Comment: I'm surprised that closure doesn't generate a notification to the committers, given that we do get notifications when a proposal advances.  Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @DoubleAA because it was closed for inactivity, not scope problems, I'd say go for it.  If we decide to rework the scope, that'll help folks figure it out.  All of my questions from last time around had reached 10, so I've reasked them (tweaking one of them).

Comment: I think this is more viable: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2138/3073